# SQL Azure - copy table between databases

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers ( [SupplierID], [CompanyName]) 
Select  [SupplierID], [CompanyName] From [AlexDB]..Suppliers
```

and got an error "reference to database and/or server name in is not supported in this version of sql server"

Any idea how to copy data between databases "inside" the server?
I can load data to client and then back to server, but this is very slow.

Answer (score 83):

I know this is old, but I had another manual solution for a one off run.

Using SQL Management Studio R2 SP1 to connect to azure, I right click the source database and select generate scripts.

during the wizard, after I have selected my tables I select that I want to output to a query window, then I click advanced. About half way down the properties window
there is an option for "type of data to script". I select that and change it to "data only", then I finish the wizard.

All I do then is check the script, rearrange the inserts for constraints, and change the using at the top to run it against my target DB.

Then I right click on the target database and select new query, copy the script into it, and run it.

Done, Data migrated.

Comment: If you're simply looking to copy DATA. Then this is the right answer.

Comment: after 32 up votes it is a shame this has not been accepted as the answer

Comment: Thanks! In my case I needed to do a point in time restore, delete all the data I don't want and then follow your instructions to get a script to apply to the original.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this method requires the data to be small enough that it's feasible to store it all in one script and copy and paste it.  Isn't this just another way of downloading it to the client and uploading it again to the target database?

Comment: Correct. As I said at the beginning of the comment "a manual solution for a one off run". I know it is not perfect but it solved my problem at the time.

Answer (score 35):

Since 2015, this can be done by use of [elastic database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) also known as [cross database queries](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/).

I created and used this template, it copies 1.5 million rows in 20 minutes:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SQL_Credential  
WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
SECRET = '<password>';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='<server>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='<db>',
    CREDENTIAL= SQL_Credential
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[source_table] (
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData
)

SELECT *
 INTO target_table
FROM source_table
```

Comment: Thanks for this method.  Effective when working with databases on Azure.

Comment: tried this but I just get incorrect syntax near 'DATA_SOURCE'  - 

tried adding a ; but same message

Comment: @james5 To help you I need to see more of your code, maybe you create a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: This code is incomplete: target_table isn't even defined.

Comment: @SUMguy remove all primary key and other constraints only WITH and  DATA_SOURCE  argument

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in a single query.

The easiest way to accomplish it is to use "Data Sync" to copy the tables.  The benefit of this is that it will also work between servers, and keep your tables in sync.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

In practise, I haven't had that great of an experience with "Data Sync" running in production, but its fine for once off jobs.

One issue with "Data Sync" is that it will create a large number of "sync" objects in your database, and deleting the actual "Data Sync" from the Azure portal may or may not clean them up.  Follow the directions in this article to clean it all up manually:

https://msgooroo.com/GoorooTHINK/Article/15141/Removing-SQL-Azure-Sync-objects-manually/5215

Comment: Sync only works if the table is less than 500 MB in size!

Answer (score 4):

SQL-Azure does not support USE  statement and effectively no cross-db queries. So the above query is bound to fail.

If you want to copy/backup the db to another sql azure db you can use the "Same-server" copying or "Cross-Server" copying in SQL-Azure. [Refer this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but i need to copy one table, from one DB to another. Any hints?

Comment: Do you need to do this once, on a scheduled regular basis e.g every night or on demand?

Comment: well, this is part of big "job" - I compare table structure to other database and adjust it accordingly, and here is need to copy data from backup database to new one

Comment: Ok, sounds like a case for SQL Azure Sync (Currently in CTP). You can configure code-independent sync relationship between your sql azure databases using Sync. More details on Sync Framework Team Blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/08/sql-azure-data-sync-update.aspx

Comment: The link has moved to:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-copy/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a tool like [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) from Red Gate Software that can move database contents from one place to another and fully supports SQL Azure. 14-day free trial should let you see if it can do what you need.

Full disclosure: I work for Red Gate Software

Answer (score 3):

An old post, but another option is the [Sql Azure Migration wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following steps, there is no straight forward way to do so. But by some trick we can.

Step1 : Create another one table with the same structure of Suppliers table inside [AlexDB], Say it as SuppliersBackup

Step2 : Create table with the same structure of Suppliers table inside DesiredDB

Step3 : Enable Data Sync Between AlexDB..Suppliers and DesiredDB..Suppliers

Step4 : Truncate data from  AlexDB..Suppliers

Step5 : Copy data from  AlexDB..SuppliersBackup to AlexDB..Suppliers

Step6 : Now run the sync

Data Copied to DesiredDB.

Answer (score 2):

If you have onprem version that has the sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, you can setup Linked Servers for both source and target database then you can run your insert into query.

See "SQL Server Support for Linked Server and Distributed Queries against Windows Azure SQL Database" in this blog: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think i found answer - no way. have to move data to client, or do some other tricks. Here a link to article with explanations: [Limitations of SQL Azure: only one DB per connection](http://accessblog.net/2011/07/limitations-of-sql-azure-only-on-db-per.html)
But any other ideas are  welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a "Linked Server" from SQL Management Studio and then query on the fully qualified table name. No need for flat files or export tables. This method also works for on-prem to azure database and vice versa.

e.g.

```
select top 1 ColA, ColB from [AZURE01_<hidden>].<hidden>_UAT_RecoveryTestSrc.dbo.FooTable order by 1 desc

select top 1 ColA, ColB from [AZURE01_<hidden>].<hidden>_UAT_RecoveryTestTgt.dbo.FooTable order by 1 desc
```

[image: Management Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A few options (rather workarounds):

1. Generate script with data
2. Use data sync in Azure
3. Use MS Access (import and then export), with many exclusions (like no GUID in Access)
4. Use 3-rd party tools like Red Gate.

Unfortunately no easy and built-in way to do that so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SSMS SQL Server Import and Export feature. This feature supports multiple connection configurations and cross-server copy of selected tables. I have tried .NET Sql Server connector, which works very well for the Azure SQL databases.