# How to copy tables from one db to another? (Sql azure)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Situation:
I have 2 azure database on the same server. All I need is to copy all tables(with data) from one db to another.
How can I make this with query help? I wasn't able to found any answer for it.

Comment: You should be able to find your luck if you search for `dump/import/export/backup/restore` with  `azure database`. You want this done only once correct? If you need to have two instances having same data you should search for `replication`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Azure - copy table between databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572754/sql-azure-copy-table-between-databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with query. Check out `Import and Export Data` program that follows sql management studio. I think it's called DTSWizard.exe. Anyway, it can copy stuff from pretty much any source.

Comment: Well, I didn't found easiest way except simply making database backup =_=. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF command, like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE destination_database_name AS COPY OF
[source_server_name.]source_database_name
```

**Same-Server Copying**

When you copy a database to make a new database on the same SQL Database server, the same logins can be used on both databases. The security principal you use to copy the database becomes the database owner (DBO) on the new database when it is created. After the copy is complete, the destination database becomes a fully functional, independent database. The logins, users, and permissions of the destination can be managed independently of the source database.

**Cross-Server Copying**

You can also copy a database between two different SQL Database servers that are in the same sub-region or data center. Because the new database is created on a different SQL Database server, it is associated with a different master database. All users in the new database maintain the permissions that they had in the source database. The security principal you use to copy the database becomes DBO on the new database when it is created and is assigned a new security identifier (SID).

For more info, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx