# Copy tables from one database to another on Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have to copy tables from one database on Azure to another which is on our virtual server there on Azure. Importing is not working. What would be the way to make this. The other issue is some of the tables have different columns can I copy matched columns only? this is sql servers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572754/sql-azure-copy-table-between-databases

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL-Azure does not support USE  statement and effectively no cross-db queries.

If you want to copy/backup the db to another sql azure db you can use the "Same-server" copying or "Cross-Server" copying in SQL-Azure. [Refer this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx)