# Azure SQL DB to Azure SQL DB replication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, paas, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

Any one have some idea which is the best way to implement continuous Replication of some DB tables from Azure SQL DB to Azure SQL DB(PaaS) in incremental way.

I have tried Data Sync preview (schema is not loading even after couple of hours),
Data Factory (Copy Data) - Fast but it is always copying entire data(duplicate records) - not an incremental way.

Please suggest.

Comment: did you check this out already ? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db-is-now-in-public-preview/

Comment: @Aravind, I have checked it, its between on-prem and Azure SQL(PaaS),

Comment: I need replication between Azure SQL(PaaS) to Azure SQL(PaaS)

Comment: if you are looking at a backup and Disaster recovery option there is Active geo replication feature. If you are looking at copying data across check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572754/sql-azure-copy-table-between-databases

Comment: I'm not interested in geo replication feature, Looking for replication of some DB tables between two different Azure SQL Databases(These DB's have 300+ tables in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achive Cloud to Cloud Migration using Data Sync Preview from Azure ASM Portal
Below are the limitations

- Maximum number of sync groups any database can belong to : 5
- Characters that cannot be used in object names : The names of objects (databases, tables, columns) cannot contain the printable characters period (.), left square bracket ([) or right square bracket (]).

[Supported limits on DB Dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBDH4.png)

Reference: http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E394315-A4CB-4C59-9696-B25215A19CEF/SQL_Data_Sync_Preview.pdf

Answer (score 2):

What is the business requirement behind this request?

1 - Do you have some reference data in database 1 and want to replicate that data to database 2?

If so, then use cross database querying if you are in the same logical server.  See my [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4550/sql-azure-cross-database-querying/) on this for details.

2 - Can you have a duplicate copy of the database in a different region?  If so, use active geo-replication to keep the database in sync.  See my [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4618/enabling-active-georeplication-for-azure-sql-database/) on this for details.

3 - If you just need a couple tables replicated and the data volume is low, then just write a simple PowerShell program (workflow) to trickle load the target from the source.

Schedule the program in Azure Automation on a timing of your choice.  I would use a flag to indicate which records have been replicated.

Place the insert into the target and update of the source flag in a transaction to guarantee consistency.  This pattern is a row by agonizing row pattern.

You can even batch the records.  Look into using the [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) in the system.data.sqlclient library of .Net.

4 - Last but not least, Azure SQL database now supports the OPENROWSET command. Unfortunately, this feature is a read only from blob storage file pattern when you are in the cloud.  The older versions of the on premise command allows you to write to a file.

I hope these suggestions help.

Happy Coding.

John
The Crafty DBA

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use Azure Data Factory, in order to do incremental updates, you would need to change your query to look at a created/modified date on the source table.  You can then take that data and put it into a "Staging Table" on the destination side, then use a stored proc activity to do your insert/update into the "Real table" and finally truncate the staging table.

Hope this helps.